# Netlogo: How can I add some conditions by using the with, if statement or else?

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I would like to count the number of turtles stopped on the road, and I want to take that X coordinate information and let it be the queue length. The following is the sample program.

```
ask turtles with [ not right-end ] ;a flag "right-end" to the red turtle for differentiation to the other blue turtles
[
  ask turtles with [ speed = 0 ] ;the speed is 0 means stopped
  [
    set top max-one-of turtles [who] ;get a turtle with biggest id
    set topx [xcor] of top
    set L count turtles with [xcor > topx] ; L is the queue length of Little's Law
  ]
]
```

Comment: Apparently you introduced globals name `top`, `topx`, and `L`?  Don't do this.  Just use locals (and correspondingly use `let` instead of `set`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having trouble understanding exactly what you want to do, but I think it is something like this:

```
to-report countRightmost ;global context
  let ts (turtles with [speed = 0 and not right-end] )
  let top max-one-of turtles [who]
  let topx [xcor] of top
  report count ts with [xcor > topx]
end
```

Comment: Hi Alan, Sorry again this. Actually, I took and checked topx and top data with BehaviorSpace results, top was all NOBODY results. However, topx had some data. I can hardly believe top data has all NOBODY. Are there any other possible reasons? If you have any guessing advice, it will be very helpful for me. Or is it better to set up a question bulletin board again? Since I wanted to know the BehaviorSpace results, I used the variable in global.

Comment: @goodgest The only way `max-one-of turtles [who]` can produce `nobody` is if there are no turtles at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to consider the condition setting method a little bit more with referring your advice.

Comment: Today, the model is perfectly completed. The syntax that you told me moved perfectly. Thank you very much for helping me. thank you for everything again!